# How can I replace a set of ENV commands in Dockerfiles with placing them to some other file, which can be reused?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have two Dockerfiles (maybe will have more) with the list of environment variables, same for the both files. Let's say:

```
ENV VAR1="value1"
ENV VAR2="value2"
ENV VAR3="value3"
```

Can I somehow move this setup to a file, which can be used in all the Dockerfiles, where it's required?
I want to remove duplicates and have a common place for setting those variables.

Comment: You can use an environment variable file with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables).

Answer (score 1):

You can split these into a custom base image.  That image would look like

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04 # or whatever else you're using
ENV VAR1="value1"
ENV VAR2="value2"
ENV VAR3="value3"
# and that's all
```

You would have to manually build this in most situations

```sh
docker build -t my/env-base -f Dockerfile.env .
```

and then you can refer to it in the downstream Dockerfiles

```sh
FROM my/env-base
# the rest of the Dockerfile commands as normal
```

Tooling like Docker Compose won't really be aware of this image layering.  There's no good way to list a base image that needs to be built as a dependency of other things, but shouldn't run a container on its own.  If you do change these values you'll have to manually rebuild the base image, then rebuild the application images.

You should also consider whether you need all of these environment variables.  In other SO questions I see variables used for filesystem paths (which can be fixed in an isolated Docker image), usernames (not a Docker concept really), credentials (keep far away from the image, it's really easy to get them back out), versions, and URLs.  You might be able to get away with using fixed values for these (use `/app` rather than `$INSTALL_PATH`), or have a sensible default in your application code.